# Detecting main URL with IdHTTPProxyServer

Tags: delphi, redirect, proxy, indy

I want to make an application to redirect websites.
It has a table with "domains" and "redirect domains".
Once it matched domain, it redirect to redirect domain.
If didn't matched, it redirect to default page.
So I created a Delphi application with IdHTTPProxyServer. 
I have configured it to even work with https using "ssleay32.dll" and "libeay32.dll".
Everything works great. 
It use "IdHTTPProxyServerHTTPBeforeCommand" event to redirect like this:

```
with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do
begin
  WriteLn('HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily');
  WriteLn('Location: ' + RedirectURL);
  WriteLn('Connection: close');
  WriteLn;
end;
```

But how do I distinguish the event call by main URL (user typed in the address bar) and other URLs?
"IdHTTPProxyServerHTTPBeforeCommand" event called lots of times when a page is loading for stat counters, facebook like buttons, etc. I don't want to redirect all of them to default page.

If this is not possible with IdHTTPProxyServer, is there any other options in Delphi or any other language (which can generate native executable. C++ preferred)?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perspective of a proxy (or the target HTTP server, for that matter), there is **no difference whatsoever** between a user-typed URL and *other* URLs. Every HTTP request is self-contained and independent of every other HTTP request. They have to processed as-is on a per-request basis.

If you want to ignore dependent URLs (images, scripts, etc), you will have to know ahead of time what the *initial* URL is, parse the data that is retrieved from that URL, keep track of any URLs the data refers to, and then ignore those URLs if you see them being requested later.  However, there is nothing in the HTTP protocol to tell you what the *initial* URL is.  There is a `Referer` request header that may help at times, as it is filled in when a browser is requesting dependent resource files, but it is also filled in when the user navigates around from one page to another, so you can't rely on the `Referer` by itself.  You will have to implement your own discovery logic to figure out the *initial* URL based on more analysis of the URLs being requested by a given client over time.

Only the client really knows what it is requesting and why, a proxy is just a gateway to reach it.  So there is only so much *smart filtering* you can do in a proxy without knowing what the client is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks, this will help. "Referer" will enough. It does not have to redirect if referred from another page. But how to check weather it has "Referer" in header? I tried "AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStrings". But it didn't read anything and it does not load the page after that

Comment: In the `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, use the `AContext.Headers` property, as the headers have already been read before the event is triggered.